# What is this electrical panel for?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I bought a rehab house and currently trying to identify what everything is in there.
There is this panel in the garage. Does anyone know what it is?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0LFC.jpg

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a sewage/septic pump controller with alarm (red light and annoying noise when the level is too high because the pump isn't pumping.) I'm surprised your copper thieves didn't trash it.

Comment: haha. lol. Do you ever sleep? Yeah - 'm honestly not sure what happened to most of copper piping:) maybe they were too lazy to get the wiring.

Comment: but I don't have public sewer - I have septic though? Is it measuring something in a septic tank?

Comment: You may have (should be able to find out at the place that issues septic permits, from when yours was built) a mound system, or a drain field that's uphill of your tank, or an "active" system of some sort. Yes, I sleep - sometimes I spend too much time here, for sure.

Comment: :) Yeah -  I [found docs for that panel](http://www.csicontrols.com/images/WD_S115.pdf). You're right. That's some sorta septic overflow protection system.

Comment: Could also be an aeration pump - some newer "active" systems have a second chamber that air is pumped through. Check with the permitting office and get a copy of the permit documents for your house - it should be enlightening - and it's good to know what you have in advance of trouble.